# Node.JS + HTTPS + Client Cert = Problems

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, client, certificate

I've been trying to get Node.JS to work with SSL and client certificates. Originally, I had tried to get it to work with restify (see my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12826711/node-js-restify-requiring-client-certificate)). When I couldn't get that to work, I backed up and tried to find an example that illustrated what I was trying to accomplish. I tried [this one](http://vanjakom.wordpress.com/2011/08/11/client-and-server-side-ssl-with-nodejs/), and I'm receiving an odd error.

Code is as follows:

Server:

```
var sys = require("sys");
var fs = require("fs");
var https = require("https");

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync("../certs/server.key"),
  cert: fs.readFileSync("../certs/server.crt"),
  ca: fs.readFileSync("../certs/ca.crt"),
  requestCert: true,
  rejectUnauthorized: true
};

https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
  console.log(req);
  res.writeHead(200);
  sys.puts("request from: " + req.connection.getPeerCertificate().subject.CN);
  res.end("Hello World, " + req.connection.getPeerCertificate().subject.CN + "\n");
}).listen(8080);

sys.puts("server started");
```

Client:

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require("fs");

var options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8080,
    path: '/hello',
    method: 'GET',
    key: fs.readFileSync("../certs/user.key"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("../certs/user.crt"),
    ca: fs.readFileSync("../certs/ca.crt"),
    passphrase: 'thepassphrase'
};

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
    console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
    console.log("headers: ", res.headers);

    res.on('data', function(d) {
        process.stdout.write(d);
    });
});

req.end();

req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.error(e);
});
```

Running test-client.js yields this:

```
{ [Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET' }
```

Attempting the same sort of thing with curl:

```
curl -k -v --key user.key --cert user.crt:thepassphrase --cacert ca.crt https://localhost:8080/hello
```

yields:

```
* About to connect() to localhost port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: ca.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to localhost:8080 
* Closing connection #0
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to localhost:8080
```

If I want to go the extra step to require a client certificate, how would I go about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about putting this server behind an nginx?

This might sound complicated, or add a lot of overhead, but I promise you it's REALLY simple, and nginx's SSL handling is easy.

Look for **proxying with nginx** ([example](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule)).

P.S
Both apps can, and probably, reside in the same server machine.

Comment: That's an intriguing answer. Can nginx pass information about the user certificate on to the ultimate destination url? Possibly by adding some parameters to the url?

Comment: Glad to hear! How did you go about it eventually, in regard to certificate forwarding through nginx? I'm just curious

Comment: I didn't forward the cert through nginx, @Poni, I authenticated with a cert against nginx, and just continued on with regular-no-client-cert https the rest of the way. Theory being that nginx wont pass the conversation along unless everything matches up.

Comment: dunno.. wasn't me. I would assume the downvote was because while the answer was useful to me, it didn't really answer the question.

Comment: @Poni, I have the same issue.  However, are there any ideas for a solution that does not involve nginx and works directly with node?

Comment: @psiphi75 see my alternative solution below

Answer (score 2):

Add `rejectUnauthorized: false` in both the server options and the client options.

That tells nodejs to accept self-signed certs. See also https://github.com/vanjakom/JavaScriptPlayground/pull/3.