# How do I trust a self signed cert using https?

Tags: node.js, ssl, https

**Edit:** I originally thought the server's certificate was self signed. Turns out it was signed by a self-signed CA certificate.

I'm trying to write a Node.js application that accesses an HTTPS site that's protected using <del>a self-signed certificate</del> certificate signed by a private, self-signed CA certificate. I'd also like to *not* completely disable certificate checking.

I tried putting the <del>self signed certificate</del> server's certificate in the request options, but that doesn't seem to be working. Anyone know how to do this?

I expect the following code to print `statusCode 200`, but instead it prints `[Error: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN]`.

I've tried similar code with [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) with the same results.

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var opts = {
    hostname: host,
    port: 443,
    path: '/',
    method: 'GET',
    ca: fs.readFileSync(serverCertificateFile, 'utf-8')
};

var req = https.request(opts, function (res) {
    console.log('statusCode', res.statusCode);
});

req.end();
req.on('error', function (err) {
    console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: I think this may be of use to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10142431/my-node-js-https-client-always-works-regardless-of-certificate-validity

Comment: @vcazan I tried adding both `agent: false` and `opts.agent = new https.Agent(opts);`, and neither one worked :-(

Comment: Are you sure you have the right certificate? Your code works for me with a self signed certificate. If I read a different (incorrect) certificate for `opts.ca` then I get `Error: DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT].`

Comment: @rhashimoto I think that was the hint I needed. It's not that the HTTPS certificate was self signed, but the server certificate was self signed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The error `[Error: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN]` is the clue to what's going on here.

That's an indication that the HTTPS server's certificate was signed by a self signed certificate, not that it's a self signed certificate itself. If the server certificate were self signed, the error would be `[Error: DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT]`.

If you provide the CA certificate instead of the server's certificate, it should work.